# Can we use the jQuery `on` for the statically created DOM element and what is the Different between on(event,selector,function) , on(event,function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

Can we use the jQuery `on` for the statically created DOM element instead of jQuery 
`click`  (I know that will work but I want to know is it good to use?)

**What is the different between this**

`$('body').on('click', '#joinSession', function(){})`  and `$('#joinSession').on('click', function() {})`

I have created the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VC4AK/) both method are giving the same result what is the significant different between this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="button" value="Create session" id="createSession"/>
        <input type="button" value="Join session" id="joinSession"/>
    </div>
    <div class="othersVideos"></div>
    <div class="ownVideo"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery script**

```
$('#createSession').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});

$('body').on('click', '#joinSession', function() {
    alert('testing')
});
```

Comment: The top is binding the click event directly to `#createSession`. The bottom is binding the click event to `body` but basically saying 'if a click event bubbles up to `body` and the event target is `#joinSession` then run this function'. The second is useful for binding an event to dynamically created/added elements.

Comment: Something to keep in mind though: letting events bubble too much up the DOM ladder can be detrimental to performance. You should try to assign events to the closest container instead of "body"

Comment: @PabloMescher I understand for example only I gave that code and I want to know what is the different your answer sounds good for one of my question

Comment: @Zenith I have another question  "for the statically created DOM element (I know that will work but I want to know is it good to use?)" is it there how its exactly duplicate

Comment: @joe  I am asking about using `on` instead of `click` I feel my question is not clear I will change it

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan Why does that matter? `click()` is just a shorthand for `on('click')`!

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan - as Zenith said, `click()` just internally maps to `on('click')` so use whichever you want. See here: http://api.jquery.com/click/#entry-longdesc

Comment: @Zenith thanks really I thought it would be different thanks man

Comment: @Joe then on('click') will be the better one is it?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#createSession').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

This will bind a click handler directly to any element(s) matching the selector. If no elements are found at the time of the bind call, it will do nothing.

```
$('body').on('click', '#joinSession', function() {
    alert('testing')
});
```

This uses event delegation and binds a click handler to the `body`. Whenever an event bubbles up to the `body`, jQuery will inspect where the event originated. If it originated from something matching the second parameter selector it will trigger the handler. This enables events to be bound to elements that may not yet exist - as long as they exist at the time the event triggers the handler will still be applied to them.

The second syntax should almost always be used as it has performance and memory benefits. For best results, you should use a selector as fast (id) and close to the element as possible instead of `body`. For more information about event delegation, check out [jqFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events).

Comment: I was with you until that last paragraph - you should not bind to the body unless you must. Preference should always be to bind to the closest container existing when the event handler is bound.

Comment: "The second syntax should almost always be used" - I disagree with this portion.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss using the non-delegating syntax simply calls the delegating syntax with `body` as the starting selector, so if you can get any more specific than body then you should be using the delegating syntax.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think jbabey saying is correct, any way +1 for explaining me the concept and your effort

Answer (score 3):

The first model bind the event directly to the element, the drawback of this method is the source element must be present when the script is executed.

The second model binds the handler to document body and it make use of event propagation to fire the handler if the selector condition is true of any of the ancestor/self of the event source element. This is useful when you are dealing with dynamic elements since when the event registration code is executed the target elements may not be present in the document

Answer (score 3):

The first example:

```
$('#createSession').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Is looking for a specific element by id. If the element does not exist on the page, the click event will not be added to this.

The second example:

```
$('body').on('click', '#joinSession', function() {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Binds the click event to the body, so even if `#joinSession` didn't exist at the time of binding the click event, you could append this element to the body later and the click event would work without you having to bind the event again. This is useful when you have a dynamic UI and you know certain elements will be added later, but you want to bind the events just once and not worry about re-binding every time a new element is added to the document.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myDiv .div').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Say you have several `.div`s inside your `#myDiv` div, the above code will attach an event to each and every matched element. Say you have 1,000 divs in it? It will attach events to 1,000 different elements.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '.div', function() {
    alert('testing')
});
```

The above, will only attach the element to `#myDiv`, and will trigger when the `click` event happens on the `#myDiv`, but only if it is also on the matching `.div` element. That way, for 1,000 divs inside `#myDiv`, you only have one event handler, preventing overhead and performance issues. Also, the latter will work on dynamically generated elements, ones that are created via AJAX or via jQuery itself as dynamic elements.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. what does "#.div" mean?

Comment: +1 for the extra info about attaching multiple handlers to multiple elements and performance/overheads.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$(element).on('event',element, function(){...}` for newly created elements so they keep the function.

Check this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VC4AK/2/)